# Graphicsmagick for node not writing the jpg

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using https://github.com/aheckmann/gm to resize an image.

```
    var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
    var fs = require('fs');

    var dir = __dirname+'/img';

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(dir + '/Desert.jpg');
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/resize.jpg');

     gm(readStream)
        .size({bufferStream: true}, function(err, size) {
            this.resize(50, 50, '%')        
            this.write(writeStream, function (err) {
            if (!err) console.log('done');
        });
     });
```

I am using the above code to resize an image....the problem is an empty image is getting generated and the error message is {[Error: write EPIPE] code:'EPIPE',errno: 'EPIPE', syscall:'write'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` method takes a string as output filename. Try the [`stream`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams) method:

```
gm(readStream)
.size({bufferStream: true}, function(err, size) {
    this.resize(50, 50, '%')        
    .stream()
    .on('end',function(){
        console.log('done');
    })
    .on('error',function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
    .pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Comment: Hi hassansin, thanks for your reply. I tried using the code u mentioned but getting the same issue an empty image is getting generated

Comment: what happens if you do `pipe(process.stdout)` instead? just want to make sure if the problem is with writing to disk or the ImageMagick itself.

Comment: same issue an empty image is getting generated.

Comment: you have ImageMagick installed right? Check by `convert --version`

Comment: Its Version is : ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q8 x86 2015-07-25

Comment: when i run this command:  convert D:/NodeJSWorkOut/Img_Resize_Ex4/img/Desert.jpg -resize 50% D:/NodeJSWorkOut/Img_Resize_Ex4/img/resize.jpg ......its generating the image as required....but through node js its giving an empty input file....i have installed both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick

Comment: @Ramu which changes you made to make it work ? I am getting same issue. Thanks